# React working slow on input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React and encountered a problem while using `onChange` method on an input field, which is generated in a big datalist.
As the `parentcomponent` is the owner of the data, I provide a `handleUpdate()` method to the child component (dataTableComponent).
Because React has to rerender the the whole datatgrid the input `onChange` is very slow.
How would I do that better? Is there a way to only update the one modified row. Or what am I getting wrong with react?

Summary: A ParentComponent contains an array with objects which is passed to the childComponent. The childComponent creates a `<table>` element with data objects attributes as columns. One column is editable and displayed as am `<input>` tag. This tag has an `onChangehandler` pointing to a function passed by the parent. So the parent handles the update and therefor rerenders the whole list. For myself is clear, that this must be slow. BUT how could I do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it like @Piyush.kappor said. But I always thought that this isn't nice. Having date saved redundant.

Now I've finally found a solution.

I left it like it was:

the app contains a list of objects and handles ever Input change.
This would be very slow, BUT now I've added a `shouldComponentUpdate()`method. So every single row checks, if it needs to be updated. If not, it wont. So I have no more lags but the data is still handled in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem earlier.

Make your each row as a seperate component and ask parent component to pass props in it. In the constructor of row component , store props in state and now just play with state, dont call parent handler to update.

If you want all your input fields updated back , use refs in the parent component to extract data

Example:

```
Class Parent extends React.component {
   render (
            this.data.map(function(value) {
               return <Row ref={value+index} data={value}/>
            })
     }
}

Class Row extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          value: this.props.data
      }
   }
   render() {
     <input value={this.state.value}/>
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use a higher order component, with the function as the props, later you declare the function and pass your info on that instead, this way you avoid using state and you use props purely instead, where you use your function when you need it

Comment: Shouldn't we avoid mixing props and state?
With your solution I would have the data redundat?

Comment: This would be one time initialization in the constructor after that you would only be setting states

Comment: I've done it like you said and re-organized my applicationstructure.
Which indeed makes more sense, as I have created a new subcomponent which contains one input field and one button. This subcomponent now performs the update itself instead of the mothercomponent. When i would need to rerender the whole list, i will pass the new components back to the mother via a callback.